# Time between loading page and finishing form

Tags: php, forms, time, spam, duration

Well, I'm only a novice PHP programmer. However, I've been working on a contact form for a live website. I'm minimizing the troubles a legitimate user has to go through in order to stop spam bots. So I have a honeypot, but I also wanted to check the time between loading the page and clicking the submit button. I am confused on how to tell php to grab the time at the load of a page and when the submit button is pressed.

I figured I'd just do a strtotime("now") twice, at the beginning of the page and when the POST variables have been sent. But...that didn't work so much. Just confused on what functions to use. Basically just checking if the form gets filled out within a few seconds, not exactly probable for a human.

Thanks, and sorry for the stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that loading the page & doing the POST on submit loads the page twice. To have it store the time you need to either save it in a cookie or session variable.  Or if this is a form & you are a novice, the best way might be to set a hidden form variable called maybe something like `start_time`.  Then when the form is submitted, compare the time stored in the `start_time` to the time generated when parsing & there you go.